# CSS: How do you center horizontally?

Tags: html, css, center

once again I have a problem with centering elements. I have this HTML/CSS:

```
<section class="btmfix">
  <div class="menurow">
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="index.html">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="product.html">PRODUCT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="request.php">REQUEST</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
  .menurow {
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
  }

  .btmfix {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .col {
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
  }

  .sml-btn {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#444;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 180px !important;
    /*  width:auto !important;*/
    padding: .3rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    /*  font-weight: 00;*/
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px #fff;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crapomat/pLt5j0sy/5/

I want the links to be centered, but I cant figure out how. I tried the margin: 0 auto; method, this is found in almost every tutorial, but it doesn't work here. Do you know why? Can you help me?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center menu horizontally you need to apply `text-align: center;` on `.col` class.

**Here is the working example:**

```css
.menurow {}

.btmfix {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.col {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

  .sml-btn {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#444;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 180px !important;
    padding: .3rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px #fff;
  }
```

```html
<section class="btmfix">
  <div class="menurow">
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="index.html">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="product.html">PRODUCT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="request.php">REQUEST</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a class="sml-btn" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take all menu group to center `text-align:center;` is enough

```
  .btmfix {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

If you also want to show menu horizantally then  `float:left;` is enough

```
.col {
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    float:left;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are given `width:0;` to `menurow` that is the issue and add col to `text-align:center`

```
.menurow {
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  text-align: center;
}
```